# О шкалах нормативности

Tags: орфоэпия

У Аванесова говорится (1987), что не все языковые факты укладываются в простое противопоставление: норма - не норма. При наличии вариативности ударения в словарях указываются **шкалы нормативности**.

1) **Равноправные варианты связаны союзом И**.

2) Если один вариант признается основным, то делается пометка "доп".

3) Если вариант находится за пределами нормы, то делаются запретительные пометки: "не рек.", "неправ.", "грубо неправ.".

И вопрос:

**Эти шкалы нормативности действуют в современном языке, они где-нибудь точно определяются?**  Есть еще пометки "простор." и "разг.", они к какому виду нормативности относятся?

По крайней мере,  **вызывают сомнение** такие высказывания:  "Но тем не менее варианты с этой пометой (допуст.) абсолютно нормативны",  и в официальной речи можно сказать БАловать".

И что такое "абсолютная нормативность"? Кажется, в словаре нет такой пометки, есть только "равноправные варианты".

Comment: Вера, а разве "абсолютная нормативность" и"равноправные варианты" не то же самое? Просто в словарях в качестве термина устоялся этот вариант "равноправные варианты".

Comment: Может быть, это одно и то же, но выражение "равноправные варианты"  больше похоже на термин, а этой области языкознания, как мне кажется, недостает строгости и определенности. Но вот пометка "доп." все-таки, я думаю,  не определяет варианты как равноправные.

Comment: Мне тоже так кажется.

Comment: Просто некоторые словари запрещают, другие допускают как просторечие, а некоторые как разговорное. Не присутствует ли здесь языковой "вкус'' лингвистов? Вряд ли можно считать нормой то, что в большинстве современных словарей отмечается как "прост.'', "не рекомендуется" и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

> У Аванесова говорится (1987), что не все языковые факты укладываются в
>   простое противопоставление: норма - не норма.

У Аванесова **нормативными** считаются варианты без помет, а также с пометами "допустимо" ***(доп.)*** и "допустимо устаревающее" ***(доп. устар.)***.

> ***Этими разновидностями помет ограничивается оценка вариантов,***
>   ***находящихся в пределах нормы.***

За пределами же литературной нормы находятся, по мнению Аванесова, лишь "варианты с  так называемыми запретительными пометами":  ***! не рек., ! неправ., ! грубо неправ.***

Не укладываются же (у Аванесова) в противопоставление ***норма /не норма*** варианты с другими пометами.

> *Остальные применяемые в словаре пометы, не являющиеся запретительными,
>   оценивают  или варианты, характерные для некоторой особой сферы
>   функционирования литературного языка, или профессиональные сферы
>   употребления.*

Такие, к примеру, пометы, как: *в поэтич. речи возм., в худож. речи возм., в народно-поэтич. речи возм., в профессион. речи, у химиков, у медиков, у музыкантов, у моряков...*

=================================

> Эти шкалы нормативности действуют в современном языке, **они где-нибудь
>   точно определяются?**

Нигде. В разных словарях, у разных лингвистов -- разные пометы... ГОСТов в лингвистике нет.

Comment: Лингвистике нужны не ГОСТы, а строгая терминология, если лингвистика считает себя наукой. Меня интересовало, как связаны между собой нормы языка и прочие пометки  в словарях. Очевидно, что они связаны. Например, ПРОСТОРЕЧИЕ  - это слова, черты произношения, НЕ ВХОДЯЩИЕ В НОРМУ ЛИТЕРАТУРНОЙ РЕЧИ, характеризующиеся оттенком упрощения, сниженности, грубоватости. А  главной чертой РАЗГОВОРНОГО СТИЛЯ является НЕСТРОГОЕ СЛЕДОВАНИЕ ЛИТЕРАТУРНОЙ НОРМЕ.  К примеру, если стоит пометка «разг.», то это уже не основная норма, и т.д. Пока, к сожалении,  у меня нет четкого понимания этих отношений.

Comment: _Vera: "Меня интересовало, как связаны между собой нормы языка и прочие пометки в словарях"._ ===

Судите сами:

===

**заморённый** у Кузнецова «разг.» (т. е., вроде бы, не совсем нормативно), у Аванесова -- без всяких помет (т. е. вполне нормативно);

===

**генезис** с ударением на втором слоге в словаре Кузнецова «разг.» (т. е. в какой-то мере в пределах нормы), у Аванесова -- «! не рек.», т. е. за пределами нормы; в РОС этот вариант вообще даётся без всяких помет, считается нормативным.

===

И т. д. и т. п.

Comment: Меня интересуют не конкретные слова, а теория вопроса.  Норма (в словарях) может определяться различным образом: а) частотность употребления; б) употребление авторитетных писателей; в) аналитическая оценка лингвистов. Норма может меняться со временем. Вот, к примеру, пометка "допуст." - к чему она относится, где этот вариант ДОПУСТИМ? В разговорной речи? Тогда должна быть пометка (разг.). Или вот от вас получено разрешение: "в официальной речи можно сказать БАловать", а на каком основании? Должна существовать высшая, образцовая форма языка, и пометка "допускается" там неуместна.

Comment: >> *Должна существовать высшая, образцовая форма языка, и пометка "допускается" там неуместна.* Язык несколько более сложная система, чем некоторым кажется.

Comment: *Нигде. В разных словарях, у разных лингвистов -- разные пометы... ГОСТов в лингвистике нет.* - не совсем так. Есть некоторые общие принципы. Но в целом с Вами согласен.

Comment: *Должна существовать высшая, образцовая форма языка, и пометка "допускается" там неуместна.*  - Мне всегда в таких случаях вспоминается *"Прожект о введении единомыслия в России".*

Answer (score 0):

Хороший вопрос. Я не очень понимаю, в чем там проблема с Аванесовым, но вообще можно уверенно сказать, что есть разные подходы к градации внутри понятия "нормативность".

Абсолютную нормативность (если без привязки к Аванесову) можно понимать как нормативную для всех стилей (

Вообще для орфоэпии можно проследить следующую шкалу

Нормативное (без помет) 
нормативное в отдельных стилях (разговорное, книжное) 
допустимо 
не рекомендуется
просторечное и/или сниженное (просторечно-сниженное, сниженное, грубое) неправильное 
грубо неправильное 
отсутствует.

Это по максимуму, обычно в словарях ограничиваются тремя-четырьмя градациями, при этом, однако, оценки "просторечные" и "сниженные/нецензцрные/обценные" слова могут вообще выпадать из такой шкалы или образовывать отдельную, параллельную основной систему оценки.

При этом есть еще и особая "сверхнормативность" - нерасмматриваемая обычно в рамках орфоэпии, но предписываемая особыми словарями для дикторов, которые даже для двух полностью нормативных вариантов (тв**о**рог и твор**о**г) дают обычно только один рекомендуемый.

Возможно понятие "абсолютной нормативности" у Аванесова как-то связано с разницей в описанных подходах, т.е. в понятие нормативности включабтся и т.н. допустимые варианты, которые не являются рекомендуемыми с точки зрения особых словарей (для дикторов).

Comment: *Возможно понятие "абсолютной нормативности" у Аванесова как-то связано с разницей в описанных подходах* - да проще там всё. кто-то неудачно выразился с этой "абсолютной", половина пошла продвигать в массы, вторая половина - прицепилась.